# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final routeArgs =
    ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
final categoryTitle = routeArgs['title'];
final categoryId = routeArgs['id'];
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(categoryTitle),
  ),
```

[Please help me with this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zbLm.png)
[This is the error I'm facing with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cm6K.png)

Comment: I suspect that `categoryTitle` is null, so just check for null `title: (categoryTitle != null ? Text(categoryTitle) : "Default title"),`

Comment: routeArgs['title'] is null so check upstream.

Answer (score 2):

i think your routeArgs['title'] is null and when you put it in text it is generating error
try

```
Text(categoryTitle??"")
```